# How to show Man Page from file?

Tags: man

I'm making a text editor, and I'm making some `man` pages for it. What I'd like to know is how to use `man` to read a file.

Also, I'm pretty sure that to make bold text in a `man` page, making `INTRODUCTION` bold would be done like this: `IINNTTRROODDUUCCTTIIOONN`?

Comment: See `man 7 groff` for how to embolden text...

Comment: I will check that.

Answer (score 3):

Never mind; it's just `man ./file_name`.

Comment: I can't, I have to wait for two days. :P